# How do I load data from S3 to Redshift using serverless architecture?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

Is there a Python demo on how to use AWS-Lambda function to load file from S3 to AWS redshift without EC2?

Answer (score 1):

There is a library available to load data into Amazon Redshift using AWS Lambda functions.

See: [A Zero-Administration Amazon Redshift Database Loader](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/a-zero-administration-amazon-redshift-database-loader/)

Comment: But it seems to use JavaScript, I want to use Python. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a Python demo but it shouldn't be hard to build. You need to write a Lambda to connect to Redshift then execute a [COPY from S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-source-s3.html). If you want a little more automation then you could [trigger it from s3:ObjectCreated](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html). That way uploading a file automatically copies it to Redshift.